# Javascript / HTML calculator, need something else method for result

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in secondary school, and we learning HTML and javascript now. I'm making a calculator (with some help from the internet) and I found eval() function. We basically haven't learned that so I need to change it to something else. Here's the code for my calculator:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Számológép</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
  function beker(szam) {
   document.szamologep.eredmeny.value = document.szamologep.eredmeny.value + szam;
  }
  function szamol() {
   var a = document.szamologep.eredmeny.value;
   if (a) {
    document.szamologep.eredmeny.value = eval(a)
   }
  }
 </script>

 <h2 align="center">Számológép!</h2>
 <form name="szamologep">
  <table border="2" align="center">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="4"><input type="text" name="eredmeny"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="beker(1)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="beker(2)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="beker(3)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="beker('+')"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="beker(4)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="beker(5)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="beker(6)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="beker('-')"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="beker(7)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="beker(8)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="beker(9)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="beker('*')"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="reset" value="C"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="beker(0)"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="szamol()"/></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="beker('/')"/></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

So I need some other way in the szamol().

We made an other calculator but with radio buttons. I'm adding the code as well, so you could se what we learned.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Névtelen 1</title>
<script>
 function szamol()
 {
  var a=parseInt(document.urlap.szam1.value);
  var b=parseInt(document.urlap.szam2.value);
  var e=0;
  if(document.urlap.muvelet[0].checked)e=a+b;
   if(document.urlap.muvelet[1].checked)e=a-b;
    if(document.urlap.muvelet[2].checked)e=a*b;
     if((document.urlap.muvelet[3].checked) &&(b!=0))e=a/b;
     if((document.urlap.muvelet[3].checked) &&(b==0))e="Nullával nem osztunk";
     
     if(document.urlap.muvelet[4].checked)
                                             {
                                              e=1;
                                              for(i=1;i<=b;i++)
                                              
                                              e=e*a;
                                             }
   document.urlap.eredmeny.value=e;
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <form name="urlap">
 <table>
 <tr>
  <td>Szam1<input type="number" name="szam1" value="0">
  <td>Szam2<input type="number" name="szam2" value="0">
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Összeadás<input type="radio" name="muvelet" checked>
      Kivon<input type="radio" name="muvelet">
      Szoroz<input type="radio" name="muvelet">
      Oszt<input type="radio" name="muvelet">
      Hatvany<input type="radio" name="muvelet">
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="OK" onclick="szamol()">
  <td><input type="reset" value="Reset">
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Eredmény:<input type="text" name="eredmeny">
 </tr>
 </table>
 
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to use a long `switch` or many `if-else` statements that look for the operator and operate on the numbers/operands according to the operator selected/pressed

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on the [comment left by Nikos M.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53305328/javascript-html-calculator-need-something-else-method-for-result#comment93491520_53305328) you'll need a way to determine which operator you're using. The code below will **only account for one operator** but will do what you're looking for if that's all you need to cover.

To clarify the bold text above, this will work for expressions that look like:

`X + Y`, `X - Y`, `X * Y`, and `X / Y`.

But won't work for expressions like:

`X + Y + Z`, `X * Y + Z / P` etc.

```
function szamol() {
        var a = document.szamologep.eredmeny.value;
        if (a) {
            var answer;
            var split = a.split(/([+,\-,*,\/]){1}/g);
            console.log('Split: ' + split);
            var first = Number(split[0]);
            var operator = String(split[1]);
            var second = Number(split[2]);
            switch(operator){
                case '+':
                    answer = first + second;
                break;
                case '-':
                    answer = first - second;
                break;
                case '*':
                    answer = first * second;
                break;
                case '/':
                    answer = first / second;
                break;
            }
            document.szamologep.eredmeny.value = answer;
        }
    }
```

We set up our empty `answer` variable, and then we split the `a` value on any operator `+, -, *, \` using a regular expression. The first element of our `split` is the first number, the second element of our `split` is our operator, and the third element of our `split` is the second number.

After we have our pieces, we create a `switch` case that checks to see which operator we're using, and does math based on that. Because the input is a text input - the JavaScript assumes we're working with strings - which is why I had to `typecast` the `first` and `second` variables as `Number()` when setting them.